# reg file is missing some entries using regspy2

Tags: registry

When I tried to generate a reg file using regspy2 for .ocx file, reg file is generated differently in two different machines.on one machine it is missing some registry entries.
can anyone suggest reason which lead to miss registry entries on that machine.

"Regspy2.exe" "path to .ocx file" >"path of output reg file"

Answer (score 0):

Setting "User Account Control Settings" to Never notify will provide all registry entries in .reg file using regspy2.

Only one observation I found out, Please add if there are any other way.